# Google Earth Engine: how to use buffer function

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, weather

I am using the following codes to extract weather data for a list of point with longitude and latitude. Now I would like to have the data for a buffer of 1km for each data.

```
var temp = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY");

// misc
var dateStart = ee.Date('1981-01-01');
var dateEnd = ee.Date('2020-12-01');

var maxtemp = 400;
var performCloudMasking = true;
var scale = temp.first().projection().nominalScale();
var crs = temp.first().projection();

var adm1Unit;

function makeDatelist(n) {
  return dateStart.advance(n,'month');
}
function maskClouds(img) {
  var cloudMask = img.select('temperature_2m').lte(maxtemp);
  return img.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

function collecttempvalue(aDay) {
  if (performCloudMasking) {
    temp = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY").map(maskClouds); 
  }
  temp = temp.select("temperature_2m");
  temp = temp.filterDate(ee.Date(aDay), ee.Date(aDay).advance(1, 'month'));
  temp = temp.mean().clip(adm1Unit);
  
  var dailyValue = temp.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    geometry: adm1Unit.geometry(), 
    scale: scale, 
    crs: crs, 
  }).get('temperature_2m');
  
  return dailyValue;
}

function appendtempvalues(feature) {
    adm1Unit = feature;
    var dailyValues = dateList.map(collecttempvalue);
    var dateValueDict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(dateList.map(formatDate), dailyValues);
    feature = feature.set(dateValueDict).setGeometry(null);
    
    return feature;
  }

function formatDate(d){
  return ee.Date(d).format('YYY-MM');
}

var n_days = dateEnd.difference(ee.Date(dateStart),'month');
var dateNumber = ee.List.sequence({start: 0, end: n_days, step: 1});
var dateList = dateNumber.map(makeDatelist);

var result = location.map(appendtempvalues);
  Export.table.toDrive({
        collection: result,
    fileFormat:"CSV",
    folder: 'GEE_no2_countries'
  });
```

Comment: The ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY dataset has a resolution of 0.1 degrees (roughly 11km/pixel).  A 1km buffer isn't going to do anything.  Also, your code is incomplete, since adm1unit isn't defined.